# Cycling through a list of list, checking and removing?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

Using the following list of lists (4 individual lists inside one big list)

```
myvariable = [['test', 'xxxx', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test'], 
              ['test', 'xxxx', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test'], 
              ['test', 'X1', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test']
             ]
```

I need to cycle through each list and check if element 0 and element 1 are the same in any of the other elements, if they are BOTH a match then it should remove the latter list (so in my example it removes the middle list.

Each time it removes an item from the list it needs to update the list.

Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It's very confusing when you use the word "elements" to refer to both elements of the inner lists and elements of the outer list in the same sentence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a list comprehension and a set to track what has been seen:

```
myvariable = [['test', 'xxxx', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test'], 
              ['test', 'xxxx', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test'], 
              ['test', 'X1', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test']
             ]

seen=set()
print [li for li in myvariable 
         if tuple(li[:2]) not in seen and not seen.add(tuple(li[:2]))]
```

Prints:

```
[['test', 'xxxx', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test'], 
 ['test', 'X1', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test']]
```

Since the list comprehension is going in order, order is maintained and the latter duplicates are deleted:

```
>>> lis=[[1,2,1],
...      [3,4,1],
...      [1,2,2],
...      [3,4,2]]
>>> seen=set()
>>> [li for li in lis if tuple(li[:2]) not in seen and not seen.add(tuple(li[:2]))]
[[1, 2, 1], [3, 4, 1]]
```

And not to be ignored, this is a lot faster way to do it:

```
from collections import OrderedDict  

lis=[[1,2,1],
     [3,4,1],
     [1,2,2],
     [3,4,2]]

def f1(lis):
    seen=set()
    return [li for li in lis 
             if tuple(li[:2]) not in seen and not seen.add(tuple(li[:2]))]       

def f2(lis):
    dic = OrderedDict()
    for item in lis:
        key = tuple(item[:2])
        if key not in dic:
            dic[key] = item

    return dic.values()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    import timeit            
    print 'f1, LC+set:',timeit.timeit("f1(lis)", setup="from __main__ import f1,lis"),'secs'
    print 'f2, OrderedDic:',timeit.timeit("f2(lis)", setup="from __main__ import f2,lis,OrderedDict"),'secs'
```

Prints:

```
f1, LC+set: 2.81167197227 secs
f2, OrderedDic: 16.4299631119 secs
```

So this approach is almost 6x faster

Answer (score 4):

Use a dict with the first two items as key:

```
>>> lis = [['test', 'xxxx', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test'], ['test', 'xxxx', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test'], ['test', 'X1', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test']]
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> dic = OrderedDict()
>>> for item in lis:
...     key = tuple(item[:2])
...     if key not in dic:
...         dic[key] = item
...         
>>> dic.values()
[
 ['test', 'xxxx', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test'],
 ['test', 'X1', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test']
]
```

Comment: Hey, I was thinking of exactly this!

Comment: Could you please change the variable name `dic` to something like `dikt`

Comment: @SrinivasReddyThatiparthy It's a hard enough word to say without sounding rude anyway :P lol

Comment: I was going to post `OrderedDict((tuple(el[:2]), el) for el in myvariable).values()` :P

Comment: @JonClements I think this will remove the first item not the second one.

Comment: I have a file constantly updating in my dropbox called dict dump. If anyone looks at my pc at the wrong moment I have some explaining to do..

Answer (score 1):

This list comprehension preserves order and eliminates all duplicates after the first.

```
>>> check = [L[0:2] for L in myvariable]
>>> [el for i, el in enumerate(myvariable) if el[0:2] not in check[:i]]
[['test', 'xxxx', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test'], 
['test', 'X1', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test']]
```

Here is a list comprehension and standard dict solution that will perform better for larger lists.

```
>>> d={}
>>> [d.setdefault(tuple(el[:2]), el) for el in myvar if tuple(el[:2]) not in d]
[['test', 'xxxx', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test'], 
['test', 'X1', 'DDDt', 'EEEst', '2323t', 'test', 'test', 'test']]
```